# Backing up an ADAM database - locking occurring

Tags: adam, ad-lds

I'm having problems trying to backup an ADAM database on Windows. it keeps saying that the server is locked.

I know that the database is used by IIS, so I've stopped all the applications and it still says that it is locked.

What else do I need to close?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to back the ADAM up? If it is by simply copying the files, you'd have to actually stop the ADAM database in the Services section of the Computer Management MMC, before copying the ADAM data directories.

At work, we use the NTBackup tool provided by Microsoft which uses the Shadow Copy service allowing you to take backups while the ADAM service is up and running. We have large ADAMs and haven't had an issue with that process.

Answer (score 0):

For ADLDS the supported guidance for backup/restore is at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725665(WS.10).aspx . For ADAM its at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737702(WS.10).aspx. Where possible its not recommended to merely stop services and copy files off the system but to use supported backup mechanisms. This is to ensure all required files were backed up in a valid state.
You might also find the http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2009/02/17/are-you-backing-up-adam.aspx article useful as it explains one reason why some 3rd party apps may fail to backup ADAM.